# Spring MVC and Thymeleaf: how to access data from templates - JoinColumns

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have this relation in `Reponses` class:

```
// Foreign Key Questions
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "idQuestion", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private Questions idQuestion;
```

I have this in my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("Listall", rservice.getAllReponse(id));
```

in my HTML page (Thymeleaf) I've tried to call the **`idChapitre`** which is in **`Questions`** class like this:

```
<tr th:each ="rep : ${Listall}">
  <th th:text ="${rep.idQuestion.idChapitre.title}"></th>
</tr>
```

With simple `JoinColumn` it works but in this case using **`JoinColumns`** doesn't work! How can I get access to the data?

Comment: please convert  FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER in your Reponses class then see if output comes

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work ! It shows me this error org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'idChapitre' cannot be found on null

Comment: it means your idQuestion is null

Comment: yes, the idQuestion is not null but the id_parent which is null, and in my case it should be null!! So, How can I do to specify that PK should be null